# How to create new tax classes programmatically in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, php, tax

I want to **create the new tax classes programmatically** and assign products in the shop. So can anyone tell me about the process?

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more like what you want.

Comment: Check this https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/tax/tax-class-new.html#:~:text=Add%20a%20new%20tax%20class,click%20Add%20New%20Tax%20Class. if you want this else need more explanation in question.

Answer (score 1):

To create new tax classes, [create a data patch](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/declarative-schema/patches/) and create and call a function something like this:

```
/**
 * Creates a product tax class with the given name.
 *
 * @param string $name
 *
 * @return TaxClassInterface
 * @throws InputException
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
 */
private function createTaxClass(string $name): TaxClassInterface
{
    $class = $this->taxClassInterfaceFactory->create();
    $class->setClassName($name);
    $class->setClassType(\Magento\Tax\Model\ClassModel::TAX_CLASS_TYPE_PRODUCT);
    $this->taxClassRepository->save($class);
    return $class;
}
```

As for how to set the tax class for your products, that depends a bit on the use case. But you can set it as the default tax class in the data patch like this:

```
/**
 * Set default product tax class to the tax class given as the parameter.
 *
 * @param TaxClassInterface $taxClass
 *
 * @return void
 */
private function setDefaultTaxClass(TaxClassInterface $taxClass)
{
    $taxClassId = $taxClass->getClassId();
    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->setup]);
    $eavSetup->updateAttribute(
        Product::ENTITY,
        'tax_class_id',
        ['default_value' => $taxClassId]
    );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this

```
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$appState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$appState->setAreaCode('adminhtml');
 
 $taxCalculationRate1 = $objectManager->create('Magento\Tax\Model\Calculation\Rate');
 $taxCalculationRate1->setCode("CODE");
 $taxCalculationRate1->setTaxCountryId("IN");
 $taxCalculationRate1->setTaxRegionId("REGION");
 $taxCalculationRate1->setZipIsRange("0");
 $taxCalculationRate1->setTaxPostcode("*");
 $taxCalculationRate1->setRate("2.5");
 $taxCalculationRate1->save(); 
 
 
 $fixtureTaxRule1 = $objectManager->create('Magento\Tax\Model\Calculation\Rule');
 $fixtureTaxRule1->setCode("CODE");
 $fixtureTaxRule1->setPriority(0);
 $fixtureTaxRule1->setCustomerTaxClassIds(array(3));
 $fixtureTaxRule1->setProductTaxClassIds(array(8));
 $fixtureTaxRule1->setTaxRateIds(array($taxCalculationRate1->getId()));
 $fixtureTaxRule1->save();
 
 echo $fixtureTaxRule1->getId();
```